# Resigning as moderator from Workplace.SE

Tags: discussion, moderators

After having been a moderator for this community for over four years, I have tendered my resignation from Workplace.SE.

I am proud to have served the community alongside Monica, who acted as a mentor when I was elected as a moderator in 2015 and has remained a guide and source of common sense ever since. I cannot in good conscience remain after her departure under these circumstances.

Thank you for trusting me to moderate this community over the past four or so years. The decision to resign was not made lightly but became the only choice at this time.

Comment: I completely get you. These are sad times indeed

Comment: Thank you for all you have contributed to this site.  It was an honor and a pleasure to work with you.

Comment: What a sad day.

Comment: I'm disappointed and upset that we got here. But the right thing is the right thing, and this is the right thing in light of the recent chain of events.

Comment: I am entirely disappointed with the whole SE network.  Disgusted...

Comment: Thank you for your work Jane. I didn't always agree with you but I've never found you to be unfair, which is all I can ask from a mod. Best of luck in the future.

Comment: @juanm any particular reason for the removal of the featured tag?

Comment: @motosubatsu I believe it's because snow put featured on, but snow had already resigned.  Another mod will need to put the featured tag back on who isn't an employee or already resigned.

Comment: This didn't age well

Comment: @Richard I haven't seen any indication of a change of policy or approach from SE, so I am remaining resigned at this stage. I respect the decision of Snow and Mister Positive to return, but for now, my resignation stands.

Comment: @JaneS - Based on the fawning response to SE's latest attempt to stamp out the fire, I suspect that Snow and Mister Positive won't be the only mods who announce that they're wanting back into the tent.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry to see you go.  We did not get to work together much due to my short tenure and the time zone difference.  I am holding out hope that this *wrong will be righted* and things go back to the way they should be.

Holding out hope for now and wishing you the best.

Comment: Thanks, @MisterPositive. If there is a change in the path forward, then I would reconsider handing in my diamond and likely departing from all Stacks. But I don't believe that will happen.

Answer (score 11):

I just requested that my profile for this site ( and 66 others ) be deleted permanently.

Comment: the only reason I didn't do that a couple of years ago, when this change started, is that I realised I can't fix broken machines without touching them... nowadays, I start wondering if some machines are even worth fixing.

Comment: @vaxquis A normal person would often shop for another machine.

Comment: @iBug I was one of the insane guys saying "if it's possible I can fix it, why should I throw it away?" ... it worked for some home appliances, in worked for some interpersonal relations, but, in hindsight, I realise that's often not the best choice, in terms of effort-to-result ratio. Sometimes giving up is what takes the most effort.

Answer (score 8):

Thank you for all the hard work as a diamond moderator - as a former diamond mod on RPG.SE I know how much thankless work is involved.

Thank you also for the principled stand, I would like to think that if my mod team had a fellow mod treated this way by the CMs we'd have mass resigned in protest as well. Well done.

Comment: Thank you. Just waiting for my diamond to dissolve, and while that is confronting, I still feel like I have made the right decision here.